# How to exclude object keys within arrays within objects from Meteor publication

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

I'm publishing some data to a Meteor blaze template, I want to return specific fields but it's a complicated object with nested arrays/objects so I'm not sure how to do this

Here's what an example of the object I'm publishing would look like

`{
  "_id": "q9i6qAZmKcf6MCPE2",
  "name": "Exam Name",
  "questions": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "question": "Question 1",
      "multipleTrue": false,
      "answers": [
        {
          "letter": "a",
          "answer": "Blah Blah",
          "correct": false <--------------
        },
        {
          "letter": "b",
          "answer": "Blah Blah",
          "correct": true <--------------
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "number": 2,
      "question": "Question 2",
      "multipleTrue": false,
      "answers": [
        {
          "letter": "a",
          "answer": "Blah Blah",
          "correct": true <--------------
        },
        {
          "letter": "b",
          "answer": "Blah Blah",
          "correct": true <--------------
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

I'm publishing this with the following code:

`return Assessments.find( {"name": "Exam Name"}, {fields: {name: 1, questions: 1}});`

How can I modify that publication to exclude the key "correct" which I have highlighted with arrows?

Questions array > question object > answers array > answers object > correct key

Comment: I would separate out answers from questions, to keep your data clean. You can also implement security on the answers collection, but you can't on fields within the questions collection

Comment: When it comes to an array mongodb `$projection` operator  has it's limitations. ref. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation,
I'd suggest redesign your data-model, and if redesign is not possible you could remove the `correct` property before publish.
i.e. `questions.forEach(function(q){ q.answers.forEach(function(a){delete a. correct}) })` , but it'll cost performance.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I decided to go with the answer I accepted because it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are publishing all, but want to exclude one or more fields (seems like it), this should work:

```
return Assessments.find( {"name": "Exam Name"}, {fields: {
    'questions.answers.correct': 0
}});
```

Comment: This works perfectly. My mistake was not using the '' around 'questions.answers' so the . was throwing an error.

Got it working perfectly now. Thanks